# $SHELL in shell script breaking code execution

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh, ubuntu-14.04

I've an automation script which will installs my some packages like ruby..etc... to update all variables its necessary for me to use $SHELL
command in script. but after this command my shell script stops execution

like

```
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
$SHELL
git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
```

like script stops execution after 3rd line and it wont go to nextline. so how to continue execution is there any $SHELL alternative

Comment: You are actually invoking a new shell there.  What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Why don't you simply execute the two first lines instead of appending them to .bashrc? If you need both to execute the lines and update the file, then do that :)

Comment: "to update all variables its necessary for me to use $SHELL command in script" - please elaborate. what are you doing and why?

Comment: `source ~/.bashrc ` should do for the variable updates

Comment: Also, you are appending this to your `.bashrc`, every time this script runs. Certainly not what you should do.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't *stop*. It just waits `$SHELL` to finish. E.g.: type `exit`.

Comment: suppose i am changing hostname like this 

     hostname mail.pmp.com
     nano /etc/hostname
     $SHELL

here in this case i need to use shell .. but after using shell .. it wont go to nextline

Comment: update your question. BTW: "it wont go to nextline" - have you even read what I wrote? you're starting a new shell...

Comment: yes i've updated.. yes i am aware of $shell creates a new shell .. but its require for me to use

Comment: After using $SHELL -c scripts continues executions ... but giving an error some thing like : /bin/bash: -c: option requires an argument